# All commands results in cannot allocate memory: fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: mongodb, nginx, amazon-ec2, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I am using an `AWS EC2` and my `EC2` configuration is `4GB RAM` and `100GB` storage. But my server shows the following error after a few days `fork: Cannot allocate memory` on every command. When I use `df` command, it shows the output as below:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M   41M  355M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       97G  8.1G   89G   9% /
tmpfs           2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/loop1       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/295
/dev/loop2       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop3       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
/dev/loop4       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/734
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

We have set up cron after every one minute to store data in MongoDB.
After this error `fork: Cannot allocate memory`, my MongoDB gets crashed. Is this reason shown below I am getting error?

```
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/loop1       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/295
/dev/loop2       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop3       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
/dev/loop4       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/734
```

Or any other reason? Please suggest me how to fix this problem.

**UPDATED**

Command `ps aux --sort -rss` output as shown below

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
ubuntu   14746  0.1  1.2 605972 50864 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:48 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   16371  0.1  1.2 603916 50752 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:47 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu    1253  0.1  1.2 605972 50744 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:56 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   21904  0.2  1.2 603912 50732 ?        Sl   Sep24   5:20 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   25045  0.1  1.2 605976 50692 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:42 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu    4465  0.1  1.2 573212 50688 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:51 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   26414  0.1  1.2 605972 50644 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:55 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   31119  0.1  1.2 603912 50620 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:50 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   30843  0.1  1.2 605972 50596 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:33 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu    6931  0.1  1.2 603912 50472 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:39 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   27885  0.1  1.2 603908 50292 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:43 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   14980  0.2  1.2 603912 50280 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:27 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   16793  0.1  1.2 605972 50232 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:03 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   31385  0.1  1.2 605976 49992 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:09 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   13127  0.1  1.2 605972 49536 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:51 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   30413  0.1  1.2 605980 49292 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:41 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu    3978  0.1  1.2 605972 49176 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:29 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   22464  0.1  1.2 603912 49048 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   21049  0.1  1.2 603912 48708 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:01 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   20409  0.2  1.2 605972 48580 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:32 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   19526  0.2  1.1 603912 48364 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:41 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   21797  0.2  1.1 605980 48032 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:07 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   25980  0.2  1.1 573200 47596 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:34 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
ubuntu   25180  0.2  0.6 382020 25888 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:21 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   16764  0.2  0.6 857164 25616 ?        Sl   Sep24   7:08 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    3910  0.1  0.6 453324 25528 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:02 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   29769  0.1  0.6 439884 25396 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:30 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   14702  0.1  0.6 443968 25376 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:29 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   22640  0.1  0.6 446268 25284 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:39 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   10698  0.1  0.6 439284 24908 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:43 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    7118  0.1  0.6 382108 24856 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:44 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   20857  0.1  0.6 381968 24852 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:31 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    9652  0.1  0.6 382320 24820 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:17 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   25578  0.1  0.6 381984 24804 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:35 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   29743  0.1  0.6 382040 24772 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:39 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   31964  0.1  0.6 382024 24772 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:34 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu     802  0.1  0.6 382060 24752 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:57 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   23609  0.1  0.6 382000 24752 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:45 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    2425  0.1  0.6 382060 24740 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:33 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   22551  0.1  0.6 381984 24740 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:45 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   11631  0.1  0.6 382060 24732 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:10 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   12422  0.2  0.6 382068 24720 ?        Sl   Sep24   5:29 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    6878  0.1  0.6 382056 24712 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:26 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    1296  0.1  0.6 382160 24704 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:59 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   30729  0.1  0.6 382360 24700 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:56 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    4985  0.1  0.6 382064 24692 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:25 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    9017  0.1  0.6 382048 24688 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:52 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    1885  0.1  0.6 382040 24680 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:52 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    3065  0.1  0.6 382016 24672 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:57 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   15708  0.1  0.6 382320 24672 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:58 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    6603  0.1  0.6 381968 24668 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:20 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    9581  0.2  0.6 455704 24664 ?        Sl   Sep24   5:36 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   16056  0.1  0.6 382024 24648 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:46 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   24948  0.1  0.6 381984 24644 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:02 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   10836  0.1  0.6 382104 24640 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:45 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    2865  0.1  0.6 381968 24632 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:35 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    3622  0.1  0.6 382024 24632 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:48 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   25284  0.1  0.6 381988 24628 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:41 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   18324  0.2  0.6 382060 24620 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:38 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   14285  0.1  0.6 381976 24616 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:46 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   29572  0.1  0.6 382064 24576 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:54 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   32483  0.1  0.6 381924 24576 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:45 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    6141  0.1  0.6 382296 24552 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:22 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   31282  0.1  0.6 381972 24552 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:38 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   17592  0.1  0.6 382088 24528 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:43 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   10968  0.1  0.6 382024 24520 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:38 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   20984  0.1  0.6 382060 24500 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:42 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   20978  0.1  0.6 381988 24496 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:19 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   24415  0.1  0.6 381972 24492 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:38 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    5606  0.1  0.6 390164 24480 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:33 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    8889  0.1  0.6 381972 24480 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:44 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   15768  0.1  0.6 381972 24452 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:38 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    5896  0.1  0.6 381972 24448 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:31 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    9024  0.1  0.6 382244 24444 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:50 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    5381  0.1  0.6 381972 24408 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:49 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   32471  0.1  0.6 382056 24400 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:52 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   31974  0.1  0.6 382092 24352 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:59 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu     603  0.1  0.6 382056 24348 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:35 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   19188  0.1  0.5 382056 24224 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:41 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   15824  0.2  0.5 381968 24200 ?        Sl   Sep24   5:30 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   27547  0.1  0.5 382280 24096 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:06 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   25498  0.1  0.5 382036 23956 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:08 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    8147  0.2  0.5 381984 23848 ?        Sl   Sep24   5:02 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    1407  0.2  0.5 382060 23796 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:49 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   30229  0.1  0.5 381992 23756 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   17822  0.1  0.5 381980 23648 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:48 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   21288  0.1  0.5 390256 23592 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:25 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    7836  0.2  0.5 455804 23560 ?        Sl   Sep24   5:35 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   24801  0.2  0.5 382048 23532 ?        Sl   Sep24   5:41 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   11738  0.1  0.5 382036 23504 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:09 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   28161  0.1  0.5 446404 23484 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:17 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    3304  0.1  0.5 381988 23464 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:45 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   12358  0.1  0.5 382060 23344 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:41 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   21739  0.1  0.5 382060 23332 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:10 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    9802  0.2  0.5 381980 23228 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:23 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   25083  0.1  0.5 382096 23100 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:42 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   27147  0.1  0.5 382056 23060 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:47 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   21416  0.1  0.5 445172 23040 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:47 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   22407  0.1  0.5 447428 23028 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:37 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   16342  0.1  0.5 382060 23008 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:14 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    7718  0.1  0.5 382004 22972 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:36 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   30414  0.1  0.5 381968 22888 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:34 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   24367  0.2  0.5 382000 22736 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:02 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   32043  0.1  0.5 382060 22600 ?        Sl   Sep24   3:43 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   23225  0.1  0.5 382028 22584 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:48 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   20706  0.1  0.5 382060 22520 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:55 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   13525  0.1  0.5 381968 22492 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:06 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    8609  0.1  0.5 381984 22420 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:24 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    5340  0.1  0.5 382024 22320 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:46 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    1534  0.1  0.5 382056 22300 ?        Sl   Sep25   1:44 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    6618  0.1  0.5 455796 22228 ?        Sl   Sep24   3:38 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    8983  0.2  0.5 382044 22188 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:06 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu    6528  0.2  0.5 382060 22128 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:46 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   20981  0.2  0.5 382064 22020 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:10 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   24469  0.1  0.5 381984 22020 ?        Sl   Sep25   3:32 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   22106  0.1  0.5 382028 21976 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:02 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   11596  0.2  0.5 381968 21804 ?        Sl   Sep24   4:37 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   16412  0.1  0.5 382044 21624 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:34 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
ubuntu   19820  0.1  0.5 434772 21552 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:36 /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
root     15557  0.0  0.4 239840 19284 ?        Ssl  Sep04  23:19 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
postgres 29110  0.0  0.3 293436 14704 ?        S    Sep19   0:10 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
root     18090  0.1  0.2 308512  8636 ?        Ssl  Sep20  14:22 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/734/amazon-ssm-agent
root       378  0.0  0.1  40736  7504 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:44 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root      5092  0.0  0.1  94892  6948 ?        Ss   06:03   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv]
root     22334  0.0  0.1  94888  6936 ?        Ss   06:38   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv]
root     11520  0.0  0.1  94888  6856 ?        Ss   05:11   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv]
root      1126  0.0  0.1 272944  5568 ?        Ssl  Sep04   1:06 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
ubuntu    5150  0.0  0.1  21480  5236 pts/0    Ss   06:03   0:00 -bash
root         1  0.0  0.1  37776  5048 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:43 /sbin/init
ubuntu   11534  0.0  0.1  45144  4584 ?        Ss   05:11   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
root      1088  0.0  0.0 833712  4044 ?        Ssl  Sep04   0:15 /usr/bin/lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs/
postgres 29113  0.0  0.0 293436  3952 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:11 postgres: writer process   
ubuntu   24451  0.0  0.0  36580  3840 pts/0    R+   06:42   0:00 ps aux --sort -rss
root     19311  0.0  0.0   5720  3512 ?        S<Ls Sep24   0:15 /sbin/iscsid
root      1184  0.0  0.0 280628  3504 ?        Ssl  Sep04   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
postgres 29115  0.0  0.0 293820  3444 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:17 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
ubuntu    5143  0.0  0.0  94892  3388 ?        S    06:03   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/0
postgres 29112  0.0  0.0 293436  3328 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process   
ubuntu   11562  0.0  0.0  94888  3324 ?        S    05:11   0:00 sshd: ubuntu
ubuntu   22369  0.0  0.0  94888  3324 ?        S    06:38   0:00 sshd: ubuntu
root      1252  0.0  0.0  65508  3128 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:05 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      1079  0.0  0.0  28988  3048 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:03 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
www-data 23982  0.0  0.0 125444  3008 ?        S    Sep24   0:17 nginx: worker process
root       454  0.0  0.0  43760  2860 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:02 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root     17433  0.0  0.0 125116  2668 ?        Ss   Sep24   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
postgres 29114  0.0  0.0 293436  2660 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:11 postgres: wal writer process   
root       888  0.0  0.0  16116  2648 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:01 /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eth0.leases eth0
syslog    1070  0.0  0.0 260628  2412 ?        Ssl  Sep04   0:17 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root      1062  0.0  0.0  26068  2008 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:21 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root       601  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      1250  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      1294  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      1531  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      1883  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      2863  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      3063  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      3301  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      3620  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      3976  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      5338  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      5379  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      5603  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      6139  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      6526  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      6616  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      6875  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      6927  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      7116  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      7698  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      7834  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      8058  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      8607  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      8733  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      8885  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      8981  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      9015  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      9579  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      9800  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     10634  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     10834  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     11594  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     11629  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     11735  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     11975  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     12420  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     13125  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     13523  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     14283  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     14698  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     14976  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     15766  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     15822  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     16340  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     16369  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     16410  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     16762  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     16791  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     17820  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     18322  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     19185  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     19523  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20405  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20704  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20855  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20979  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20982  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     21047  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     21286  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     21414  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     21795  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     22104  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     22401  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     22455  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     22638  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     23223  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     23606  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     24365  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     24413  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     24467  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     24799  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     24946  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     25043  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     25178  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     25282  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     25496  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     25576  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     25942  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     26412  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     27145  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     27882  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     29751  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     30227  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     30409  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     30410  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     30726  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     31109  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     31280  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     31383  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     31962  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     31972  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     32041  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     32469  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     16053  0.0  0.0  49372  1964 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     30840  0.0  0.0  49372  1964 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     14742  0.0  0.0  49372  1960 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     21899  0.0  0.0  49372  1960 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      4981  0.0  0.0  49372  1952 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      6600  0.0  0.0  49372  1948 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
ubuntu   11536  0.0  0.0  63320  1944 ?        S    05:11   0:00 (sd-pam)
root     10966  0.0  0.0  49372  1888 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     17512  0.0  0.0  49372  1888 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     28158  0.0  0.0  49372  1888 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root      9626  0.0  0.0  49372  1876 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     21599  0.0  0.0  49372  1852 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     32261  0.0  0.0  49372  1844 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20753  0.0  0.0  49372  1840 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     25038  0.0  0.0  49372  1836 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
www-data 23981  0.0  0.0 125444  1780 ?        S    Sep24   0:26 nginx: worker process
root     15570  0.0  0.0  49372  1776 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
postgres 29116  0.0  0.0 148420  1776 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:06 postgres: stats collector process
```

Previously we had not installed nginx server for that we directly used `crontab -e`. In home directory we created one folder and in that folder we created two files and set crons and `crontab -e` command showed this

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py
```

Comment: can you check once mongo log? so that you can trace the errormore accurately ?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty I can't open because log file's size is more than 6 GB so i deleted that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `/dev/loop*` are virtual devices to mount disk images used by snapd service, it is perfectly normal that they are at 100% because these are read only.

The error `fork: Cannot allocate memory` means that your server is swapping (It runs out of free memory). I am not sure why you were looking at `df` output but this is not a disk space related issue, unless you are looking for a swap partition related solution but I guess that is not the case here.

You mentioned "*my server shows error after few day's*", which seems to be a symptom of memory leak occurring somewhere.

If I were you I would start by finding out what is using up all the memory. You can run the following command to sort processes by memory usage:

```
ps aux --sort -rss
```

You could also use `top` or `htop` for a real-time debugging session.

For your [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB), mongodb (wiredTiger) by default uses the larger of either 60% of RAM minus 1GB, or 1GB.

Once you figure out the culprit you either want to fix it or accept the fact that you need more RAM. If it is the later case you might want to upgrade your instance to 8GB RAM or even more.

Comment: I used this command `ps aux --sort -rss` and I am getting in response cron lists like this `root     20704  0.0  0.0  49372  1972 ?        S    Sep25   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f`  also `ubuntu   16412  0.1  0.5 382044 21624 ?        Sl   Sep25   2:34 /usr/bin/python3 /home/test.py`

Comment: why am i getting this kind of list? I am new at thing whole thing, can you please explain of the purpose of `reference` mentioned above?

Comment: It is really hard to see the output like this, can you update your question with an UPDATED section with `ps aux --sort -rss` output?

Comment: Basically you want to look for the `%MEM` column and check the processes with a high value. `ps aux` gives you a bunch of information of your system processes - PID, CPU usage, memory usage etc. `--sort -rss` flag sort in by descending order of memory usage.

Comment: Ok now that I see you have so many instances of the /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/test.py and /usr/bin/python3 /home/folder_name/m2.py processes, there is definitely something wrong. Each of them is using 0.6 to 1.2% no wonder you are swapping. Can you explain more on how you are running these? Are these processes supposed to be running at same time? They might not be quitting properly. You might also want to add an UPDATED header otherwise the answer is not going to make sense to your question.

Comment: The question now is do you expect to run multiple instances of the python script in parallel? My guess is that your python script load a dataset from your mongodb, then takes a long time to process it. Your 4GB ram server obviously is incapable of that. If you only need one instance of the python script checkout flock for cronjobs, you can easily find guides on google. Otherwise either upgrade your server for more ram or refactor your python script.